# Does responsive design have to be fluid layout?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

At the outset let me clarify - please do not point me to links about responsive designs. I have done enough googling for a life time, yet am here.  I am looking for specific tips, not tutorials.

I had a fixed width layout web design till yesterday when a Google search result of my site announced that my site is not mobile friendly! And I took the Google mobile friendly test as advised. Of course, my website was declared unfriendly to mobiles as it would mean horizontal scrolling for users. However when I tried to make all my fixed width including body, containers etc fluid by using percentage, it looked splendid on my laptop. But browser resizing and mobile screen resolutions now make my pages look like hurricane hit!

I am hating the fluid thing and more so ever the responsive design thing! So much work in trying to decide how to redesign and still not able to make things work. I have tried using viewport, @media screen only, a separate CSS for specific screen size etc. I'm just about to explode! I have a website with a couple of thousand pages. Though I have common header and footer, I can't change the html/CSS of the inner parts of all pages. I am not able to even make a decent home page.

So my question is, is it still possible to have fixed width layout and still become mobile friendly ?  That way I don't have to tear my hair to please Google! Or is there actually some tips to easily change my CSS to a responsive CSS or some converter program or CSS checker and adviser, etc? I believe Stack Overflow is a fixed width design and they still don't seem to have any trouble.

The site is [here](http://www.landshoppe.com).

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to be mobile friendly with fixed layout? If it's fixed then it is fixed. It can't adapt to new screen size. I don't see where problem is with responsive design for your page as it have really small amount of css styling. You just need to do it right. And a note, you set `<link>` for some css and font in your page at the bottom of document, above `</html>`, but it must go in `<head>`...

Comment: Right jakob. The <links are there becoz google told me to defer/load asynchrounously the css . And some google result told me that this is one way of deferring. I did try some javascript that dynamically added link to head to defer css but that did not work. As for the fluid divs, I am trying to change all my fix width to percentage....now google loves my mobile friendliness ...but the design is a mess !!

Comment: I need to know if there are some critical tips on fluid designing ! .....like ...are floats an issue when doing responsive designing...?

Comment: @user3526204 Stop throwing around buzz words like they mean something.  "Responsive" and "fluid" are all meaningless really.  At the end of the day, you just need to build a web page, and CSS is your only tool available for styling.  I've looked at your site, and have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, so it's difficult to offer specific advice.  My main advice to you:  Purchase an existing website template and modify it for what you need.

Comment: @brad it is obvious i wanted to code my own pages. That's why I was going through all this trouble. I could have bought templates and used them. Then I wouldn't have been hear asking for coding solutions !! I guess this place is for that right ?

Comment: @user3526204 If you want to learn how to make pages, by all means go for it.  If you want to get your site done, start with something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you need to have fluid measurements in order to create a mobile friendly site. There are certain elements that can have fixed measurements (i.e.: height of nav bar), but most need to be fluid, so that it can properly be displayed in both desktop and mobile settings.

The main problem with your site is that your grid is not properly done. It is incredibly time-consuming to create your own grid with rows and columns. I would recommend learning Bootstrap, a common CSS/JavaScript framework. Just the grid system alone (built only on CSS), would immensely cut down the time it would take to build your site, and fix most of the problems that exist due to your containers/rows not being responsive.

You can download Bootstrap at http://getbootstrap.com/, and in addition learn the grid from W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Thanks rich22, i was trying to build my own grid and containers as I wasn't familiar with frameworks like bootstrap. Guess I should head towards that. However, one thing I learnt in my efforts is that, to convert an existing non-mobile css to a mobile friendly css, it is  important to ensure that there is no inline styling in any of the pages. As they will render same on any device in spite adding an @media query ! I hadn't realized that.

Comment: Yes that is true. You should not use inline styling in general, as you will learn more about attributes (there are tons), it can significantly clutter up your HTML and it is much easier to read/edit CSS properties if the HTML and CSS is divided. I'd recommend learning about CSS selectors, if you haven't already so you can target any element or elements on the page. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp . Good luck!